# Ruby on Rails - multiple edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple) did a great tutorial on how to do multiple edit from a selection.  But I want to build on top of it.  What if I want to do more actions (edit and destroy)?  This is similar to  gmails ability to preform different actions on mail.

I created my form and I have a drop down menu of the action.  The form goes to a action in my controller which is supposed to redirect it to the correct action (edit vs destroy).  I'm trying to do this with [redirect_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/redirect_to) and pass my parameters along, but its not working correctly.

```
def action
  if params[:perform_action] == 'edit'
    redirect_to :action => 'edit_multiple', :structure_ids => params[:structure_ids]
  elsif params[:perform_action] == 'destroy'
    redirect_to destroy_multiple_structures_path, :structure_ids => params[:structure_ids]
  end
end
```

But this isn't working properly.  My edit_multiple is actually redirected to the show action.  Even though I have it set up in my routes and all.

How do I properly pass the parameters on?  Or is it a matter of the method its being passed (and if so, how do I change that?)
Or what is the proper way to do this (if this isn't it)?

I tired passing params on but that didn't work.

I am using a collection in routes.rb but I can't figure out how to change the redirect_to to be giving a POST.  Any ideas?

Comment: also, I have a edit_multiple_structures_path but I can't figure out how to pass params along with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I can't seem to figure out how to get method to change in redirect_to and I can't figure out how to get the params passed correctly. THEREFORE I "cheated" and used jQuery to change the action of the form itself:

```
$("#action").change(function(e){
    var changeTo = $(e.target);
    var value = changeTo.attr("value");
    if(value == 'edit'){
        $("form").attr("action","/myController/edit_multiple");
        $("form").attr("method","POST");
    }
    if(value == 'destroy'){
        $("form").attr("action","/myController/destroy_multiple");
        $("form").attr("method","DELETE");

    }
});
```

Its not optimized but it works.  And action is the id of the select tag.  Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

FYI- update_all or delete_all is your friend, here.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail-like functionality for delete, archive, etc needs no form, so just create a button or link with the desired functionality.
You only need a form for changing content.